# In R, how to use values as the variable names

Tags: r, get

I know the function `get` can help you transform values to variable names, like `get(test[1])`. But I find it is not compatible when the values is in a list format. Look at below example:

```
> A = c("obj1$length","obj1$width","obj1$height","obj1$weight")
> obj1 <- NULL
> obj1$length=c(1:4);obj1$width=c(5:8);obj1$height=c(9:12);obj1$weight=c(13:16)
> get(A[1])
Error in get(A[1]) : object 'obj1$length' not found
```

In this case, how can I retrieve the variable name?

Comment: names(obj1)[1] would get the variable name 'length'

Comment: I don't understand how you think `get` works. The variable name IS 'obj1$length'. Using your code, the proper way to get 'obj1$length' would be like `get('obj1')$length`. I don't know why you would do it this way, though.

Answer (score 2):

`get` doesn't work like that you need to specify the variable and environment (the list is coerced to one) separately:

```
get("length",obj1)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Do do it with the data you have, you need to use `eval` and `parse`:

```
eval(parse(text=A[1]))
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

However, I suggest you rethink your approach to the problem as `get`, `eval` and `parse` are blunt tools that can bite you later.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `eval()` function will do the trick, among other uses.

> eval(A[1])
>
> >[1] 1 2 3 4

You could also find useful this simple function I implemented (based in the commonly used combo eval, parse, paste):

> evaluate<-function(..., envir=.GlobalEnv){ eval(parse(text=paste( ... ,sep="")), envir=envir) }

It concatenates and evaluates several character type objects. If you want it to be used inside another function, add at the begining of your function

> envir <- environment()

and use it like this:

> evaluate([some character objects], envir=envir)

Try, for example

> myvariable1<-"aaa"; myvariable2<-"bbb"; aaa<-15; bbb<-3
>
> evaluate(myvariable1," * ",myvariable2).

I find it very usefull when I have to evaluate similar sentences with several variables, or when I want to create variables with automatically generated names.

> for(i in 1:100){evaluate("variable",i,"<-2*",i)}

Comment: If this function actually exists and does what you say it does, you will at least need to say what package it is in.

Comment: My mistake, @joran. I use a function of my own to evaluate characters and objects containing characters that I named like that and I got confused for a moment. Anyhow, here it is, if it can help anyone:

evaluate<-function(..., envir=.GlobalEnv){ 
  eval(parse(text=paste( ... ,sep="")), envir=envir) }

Comment: @Rufo : I think you should incorporate your `evaluate` in your actual answer; I guess it could, indeed, be a useful wrapper. Also, could you explain the indented usage of `...`? E.g. `evaluate(A[1], A[2])` doesn't do what I expected. Perhaps you meant to `lapply(list(...), eval)` etc.?

Comment: @joran: `...` in my function `evaluate` can be several character objects. They get concatenated and evaluated. Indeed, `evaluate(A[1], A[2])` wont work, as it would try to evaluate the sentence `obj1$lengthobj1$width` in R (which doesn't make sense). Try, for example `myvariable1<-"aaa"; myvariable2<-"bbb"; aaa<-15; bbb<-3; evaluate(myvariable1,"*",myvariable2)`. I find it very usefull when I have to evaluate similar sentences with several variables, or when I want to create variables with automatic names. `for(i in 1:100){evaluate("variable",i,"<-2*",i)}`